# CSS Conditional Use of @import

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Say I have 2 separate CSS; desktop.css and ipad.css
Now desktop.css is already called across 100 diff HTMLs and I want to apply a new ipad.css on these 100 htmls now. Now in desktop.css, can I use a @import at the top saying

```
@import "ipad.css"
```

Then in ipad.css, I use a @media check for iPad using

```
@media only screen and (device-width : 768px) 
{  
/* All iPad style definitions here */
}
```

My question is;

1. Is this approach fine and will it work i.e. sepearte CSS will get applied to desktop Vs iPad?
2. Since I am writing @import, will the
   ipad.css get loaded always even if it    is desktop and
       will that have a huge    impact on
       performance (page loading)

Please suggest any other approach (except using link media=.device-width..) since I do not want to update anything within the html page itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this approach fine and will it work i.e. sepearte CSS will get applied to desktop Vs iPad?

No. It makes the assumption that the iPad and only the iPad will have a device-width of 768px.

> Since I am writing @import, will the ipad.css get loaded always even if it is desktop and

The media query is inside the imported file so the file will have to be loaded because the browser can be aware there is a media query.

> will that have a huge impact on performance (page loading)

There will be an additional HTTP request. However much data is in the file will have to be loaded. 'huge' is a relative concept though.

> Please suggest any other approach

Apply the media query to the `@import` statement itself.

Comment: ok..For a moment assume that only the iPad has a device-width of 768px..Will the overall way of writing the CSS work..i mean css1 for desktop and css2 for ipad... I mean to say is it theoretically correct..

Comment: Also I  did not quite understand what you mean exactly by "Apply the media query to the @import statement itself."

Comment: If you're suggesting doing something like `@media { @import ipad.css }`, this will not work. The import is never ran, so the styles do not show up.

Comment: What is the correct and best approach then? Could you please provide the exact code..

Comment: Hey RussellUresti , But I see something on these pages which show conditional import
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html & 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/